# Format date into another format return wrong date

Tags: scala, date

So i have `dd/mm/yyyy` date format and i want to convert it into date `dd MMM, yyyy` format.
This is what i have try:

```
val s: String = "27/04/2014"
val simpleDateFormat: SimpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/mm/yyyy")
val date2 = simpleDateFormat.parse(s)
val df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM, yyyy")
println(df.format(date2))
```

Result:

```
27 Jan, 2014 res0: Unit = ()
```

Comment: `mm` = minutes, `MM` = months; see the API docs of [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change the

```
val simpleDateFormat: SimpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/mm/yyyy")
```

to

```
val simpleDateFormat: SimpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy")
```

check this out for all the codes:
http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html